# Does @Asynchronous have a Timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, timeout, ejb

When i call a Method like this:

```
@Asynchronous
public void cantstopme() {
  for(;;);
}
```

Would it run forever or would the Application Server kill it after a certain time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time a method annotated `@Asynchronous` is invoked by anyone it will immediately return regardless of how long the method actually takes.

Each invocation should return a `Future` object that essentially starts out empty and will later have its value filled in by the container when the related method call actually completes.

For example:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> cantstopme() {

}
```

and then call it this way:

```
final Future<String> request = cantstopme();
```

And later you could ask for the result using the Future.get() method with a specific timeout, i.e:

```
request.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: It is not mandatory to return a Future object. It could also be a void method. The difference is that, asynchronous methods that return void can’t declare application exceptions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html

Comment: Won't calling `AsyncResult#get(timeout, unit)` result in a `IllegalStateException`? At least that is what I conclude from reading the implementation in Java EE 7.

Comment: How did you end up with that conclusion? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/AsyncResult.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Answer (score 3):

This code will run forever. AS or standalone app, Java has no legal means to interrupt a thread if the running code is not designed to be interrupted.

Comment: Java may not have it but maybe the EJB Container does..?